# Blazor Hybrid (MAUI) app works in iOS simulator, but not during App Review process

Tags: maui, .net-maui, maui-blazor

I recently finished developing my first Blazor Hybrid app. Everything went swimmingly. So I submitted it to the store and got back a rejection saying it crashes on start. The crash dump was very uninformative and I don't really know what to do next.The Android version is already published and running perfectly on Android phones. Below is the crash dump that Apple made available. I won't bother posting the csproj, because it's basically unchanged from when I created it using VS 2022 Preview. Of course I added some dependencies, but that's about it.

Can anyone please help me diagnose this? Is there a way to run on a real iPhone using VS 2022 Preview for Mac?

How might I get an actual stack if I were to submit a new version Apple? Any why does the dump not contain a stack?

**Edit: got it running on a physical iPad and I get the same exact crash report as below. No actual stack or anything remotely symbolicated. Anyone know why?**

Here is the relevant publish section from the csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="$(TargetFramework.Contains('-ios')) and '$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
     <CodesignProvision>Automatic</CodesignProvision>
     <CodesignEntitlements>Entitlements.plist</CodesignEntitlements>
     <CodesignKey>iPhone Distribution</CodesignKey>
     <DebugType>none</DebugType>
     <Optimize>True</Optimize>
     <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
     <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
     <ConsolePause>False</ConsolePause>
     <MtouchArch>ARMv7, ARM64</MtouchArch>
     <MtouchLink>SdkOnly</MtouchLink>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

And here is the "dump" with sensitive stuff taken out:

```
    {
  "app_name": "xxx",
  "timestamp": "2022-08-17 09:48:02.00 -0700",
  "app_version": "2.0.2",
  "slice_uuid": "c4517caa-e8a8-33db-aeff-35bea44c52c7",
  "adam_id": "1498333673",
  "build_version": "202",
  "platform": 2,
  "bundleID": "xxx",
  "share_with_app_devs": 0,
  "is_first_party": 0,
  "bug_type": "309",
  "os_version": "iPhone OS 15.6 (19G71)",
  "incident_id": "49BECBB4-1A4A-48D8-AC7A-72744145E305",
  "name": "xxx"
}
{
  "uptime": 410000,
  "procLaunch": "2022-08-17 09:48:01.7292 -0700",
  "procRole": "Foreground",
  "version": 2,
  "userID": 501,
  "deployVersion": 210,
  "modelCode": "iPad11,3",
  "procStartAbsTime": 10024794259695,
  "coalitionID": 844,
  "osVersion": {
    "isEmbedded": true,
    "train": "iPhone OS 15.6",
    "releaseType": "User",
    "build": "19G71"
  },
  "captureTime": "2022-08-17 09:48:01.8504 -0700",
  "incident": "49BECBB4-1A4A-48D8-AC7A-72744145E305",
  "bug_type": "309",
  "pid": 43760,
  "procExitAbsTime": 10024797152548,
  "cpuType": "ARM-64",
  "procName": "xxx",
  "procPath": "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/7017F8DA-1FAD-4DDE-BCC5-F7981C60C973\/xxx",
  "bundleInfo": {
    "CFBundleShortVersionString": "2.0.2",
    "CFBundleVersion": "202",
    "CFBundleIdentifier": "xxx",
    "DTAppStoreToolsBuild": "13F100"
  },
  "storeInfo": {
    "itemID": "1498333673",
    "deviceIdentifierForVendor": "39D05405-6205-4451-9244-34FFEEC95A57",
    "thirdParty": true,
    "softwareVersionExternalIdentifier": "851585260"
  },
  "parentProc": "launchd",
  "parentPid": 1,
  "coalitionName": "xxx",
  "crashReporterKey": "5c0b0236026542e0d88176f980a207075623f495",
  "isCorpse": 1,
  "exception": {
    "codes": "0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000",
    "rawCodes": [
      0,
      0
    ],
    "type": "EXC_CRASH",
    "signal": "SIGABRT"
  },
  "asi": {
    "libsystem_c.dylib": [
      "abort() called"
    ]
  },
  "faultingThread": 0,
  "threads": [
    {
      "triggered": true,
      "id": 1576930,
      "threadState": {
        "x": [
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 10000000
          },
          {
            "value": 28
          },
          {
            "value": 768
          },
          {
            "value": 9797698587401187317
          },
          {
            "value": 9797698591528184437
          },
          {
            "value": 1000
          },
          {
            "value": 2045
          },
          {
            "value": 54
          },
          {
            "value": 2407608375
          },
          {
            "value": 2409707520
          },
          {
            "value": 39
          },
          {
            "value": 328
          },
          {
            "value": 4463068544,
            "symbolLocation": 0,
            "symbol": "_main_thread"
          },
          {
            "value": 0
          },
          {
            "value": 6
          },
          {
            "value": 259
          },
          {
            "value": 4463068768,
            "symbolLocation": 224,
            "symbol": "_main_thread"
          },
          {
            "value": 12
          },
          {
            "value": 27280
          },
          {
            "value": 18446744073709551615
          },
          {
            "value": 4457047756
          },
          {
            "value": 1056
          },
          {
            "value": 4551975392
          },
          {
            "value": 4530786760
          }
        ],
        "flavor": "ARM_THREAD_STATE64",
        "lr": {
          "value": 8342680508
        },
        "cpsr": {
          "value": 1073741824
        },
        "fp": {
          "value": 6102932768
        },
        "sp": {
          "value": 6102932736
        },
        "esr": {
          "value": 1442840704,
          "description": " Address size fault"
        },
        "pc": {
          "value": 7384791864,
          "matchesCrashFrame": 1
        },
        "far": {
          "value": 4530305400
        }
      },
      "name": "tid_103",
      "queue": "com.apple.main-thread",
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 31544,
          "symbol": "__pthread_kill",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 29628,
          "symbol": "pthread_kill",
          "symbolLocation": 268,
          "imageIndex": 1
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 492620,
          "symbol": "__abort",
          "symbolLocation": 128,
          "imageIndex": 2
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 132400,
          "symbol": "abort",
          "symbolLocation": 180,
          "imageIndex": 2
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 83099388,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 86072624,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 86072932,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 85666320,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 84529256,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 84527808,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 84535064,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 83132492,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 84535924,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 84525344,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 85701052,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 85666228,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 84529256,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 84527808,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 84535064,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 83097272,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 83133596,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 86087812,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 105892,
          "symbol": "start",
          "symbolLocation": 520,
          "imageIndex": 4
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1576933,
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 3668,
          "symbol": "start_wqthread",
          "symbolLocation": 0,
          "imageIndex": 1
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 1576934,
      "name": "SGen worker",
      "frames": [
        {
          "imageOffset": 7972,
          "symbol": "__psynch_cvwait",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 0
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 33432,
          "symbol": "_pthread_cond_wait",
          "symbolLocation": 1236,
          "imageIndex": 1
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 85559788,
          "imageIndex": 3
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 6572,
          "symbol": "_pthread_start",
          "symbolLocation": 148,
          "imageIndex": 1
        },
        {
          "imageOffset": 3688,
          "symbol": "thread_start",
          "symbolLocation": 8,
          "imageIndex": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "usedImages": [
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 7384760320,
      "size": 221184,
      "uuid": "9ab02ad0-348c-30cb-99f4-0979c2d47515",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_kernel.dylib",
      "name": "libsystem_kernel.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 8342650880,
      "size": 49152,
      "uuid": "a8989ffb-1414-39dc-a1a8-1534f21923fe",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_pthread.dylib",
      "name": "libsystem_pthread.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 6649233408,
      "size": 524288,
      "uuid": "86a1a24a-ce35-3769-ba69-60f28353281e",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/system\/libsystem_c.dylib",
      "name": "libsystem_c.dylib"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64",
      "base": 4363943936,
      "size": 89866240,
      "uuid": "c4517caa-e8a8-33db-aeff-35bea44c52c7",
      "path": "\/private\/var\/containers\/Bundle\/Application\/7017F8DA-1FAD-4DDE-BCC5-F7981C60C973\/xxx",
      "name": "xxx"
    },
    {
      "source": "P",
      "arch": "arm64e",
      "base": 4462624768,
      "size": 360448,
      "uuid": "66e1fb26-68f8-379b-a052-eb8b8291b5e1",
      "path": "\/usr\/lib\/dyld",
      "name": "dyld"
    }
  ],
  "sharedCache": {
    "base": 6459588608,
    "size": 2509930496,
    "uuid": "c5fbbd80-45de-3edf-969b-119fca42580a"
  },
  "vmSummary": "ReadOnly portion of Libraries: Total=810.9M resident=0K(0%) swapped_out_or_unallocated=810.9M(100%)\nWritable regions: Total=587.4M written=0K(0%) resident=0K(0%) swapped_out=0K(0%) unallocated=587.4M(100%)\n\n                                VIRTUAL   REGION \nREGION TYPE                        SIZE    COUNT (non-coalesced) \n===========                     =======  ======= \nActivity Tracing                   256K        1 \nColorSync                           32K        2 \nKernel Alloc Once                   32K        1 \nMALLOC                           564.2M       93 \nMALLOC guard page                   64K        4 \nSTACK GUARD                         48K        3 \nStack                             2096K        3 \nVM_ALLOCATE                       10.6M       18 \nVM_ALLOCATE (reserved)            8192K        1         reserved VM address space (unallocated)\n__AUTH                            3816K      409 \n__AUTH_CONST                      21.3M      551 \n__CTF                               756        1 \n__DATA                            16.5M      542 \n__DATA_CONST                      21.9M      559 \n__DATA_DIRTY                      2067K      465 \n__FONT_DATA                          4K        1 \n__LINKEDIT                       187.4M        3 \n__OBJC_CONST                      5299K      379 \n__OBJC_RO                         91.3M        1 \n__OBJC_RW                         3472K        1 \n__TEXT                           623.5M      567 \n__UNICODE                          592K        1 \ndyld private memory               1024K        1 \nmapped file                       15.0M      127 \nshared memory                       32K        2 \n===========                     =======  ======= \nTOTAL                              1.5G     3736 \nTOTAL, minus reserved VM space     1.5G     3736 \n",
  "legacyInfo": {
    "threadTriggered": {
      "name": "tid_103",
      "queue": "com.apple.main-thread"
    }
  },
  "trialInfo": {
    "rollouts": [
      {
        "rolloutId": "5ffde50ce2aacd000d47a95f",
        "factorPackIds": {},
        "deploymentId": 240000179
      },
      {
        "rolloutId": "610d4ab6fc54bc33898403cd",
        "factorPackIds": {
          "SIRI_UNDERSTANDING_MORPHUN": "6201e7dc295c182621ecf027"
        },
        "deploymentId": 240000257
      }
    ],
    "experiments": [
      {
        "treatmentId": "06dd09ac-4929-4c36-8aa5-454eba81318c",
        "experimentId": "60cb9b8392f6a873b12a8ba6",
        "deploymentId": 400000038
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tested the Release (not debug) build on both the simulator AND a real device?

Comment: I have tested the Release build on the simulator for multiple devices and it works. I did not test on a real device because I don't know how to do that from VS 2022 Preview for Mac. Any thoughts?

Comment: there is an entire section of docs on how to do this.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/

Comment: Oh I see, the same procedure for Xamarin applies to Maui? Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: Same issue here, did you find a solution @TinyTownSoftware